# FAILED cassandra-operator-1.0.0

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, apiconnect

I am getting the below error while setting up cassandra-operator.

```
$ helm list
NAME            REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS  CHART                           APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
r8e789c134d     1               Fri Jun 26 07:00:39 2020        FAILED  cassandra-operator-1.0.0        1.0.1           apiconnect

$ helm status r8e789c134d
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Jun 26 07:00:39 2020
NAMESPACE: apiconnect
STATUS: FAILED

NOTES:
1. Get the cassandra-cluster admin URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace apiconnect -l "app=cassandra-operator,release=r8e789c134d" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:1770 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 1770:1770
```

$ export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace apiconnect -l "app=cassandra-operator,release=r8e789c134d" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
error: error executing jsonpath "{.items[0].metadata.name}": Error executing template: array index out of bounds: index 0, length 0. Printing more information for debugging the template:
template was:
{.items[0].metadata.name}
object given to jsonpath engine was:
map[string]interface {}{"apiVersion":"v1", "items":[]interface {}{}, "kind":"List", "metadata":map[string]interface {}{"resourceVersion":"", "selfLink":""}}

Please let me know if there is any issue in the set up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as the status is "FAILED" the helm was not completely deployed, that's why you are not being able to call the admin URL. I tried to find this `cassandra-operator` but it's not on Helm Hub. Would you share the link of the helm chart you are trying to deploy?

Comment: Thank you for the uddate. 
I am following the below link to configure the cassndra-operator. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.install.doc/tapic_install_createCRDs_Kubernetes.html

Comment: The link you provided, does not mention the source of the cassandra operator. Is it this one: https://github.com/datastax/cass-operator? Are you working on IBM Cloud? Your goal Is to deploy Cassandra Operator or IBM API Connect?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. 
Yes, I am working on IBM cloud. My goal is to deploy the IBM API connect which required a Cassandra operator. No I am not following the link you provided? following the IBM documentation.